# É possível compilar um app utilizando Java e Kotlin juntos?

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

Posso fazer parte do código em Java e outra parte com Kotlin?
Alguém sabe me dizer?

Comment: Hipoteticamente sim. Kotlin funciona em cima da JVM, então é possível chamar coisas do Java no Kotlin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sim, pode. É um recurso propalado pela Google que a nova linguagem do Android seja interoperável com Java; você pode criar uma classe em Java e outra em Kotlin, cada uma irá ser compilada para um arquivo `.class`, e uma pode chamar a outra no código (Kotlin chamar o Java ou o Java chamar Kotlin).

Você pode inclusive ir adotando o Kotlin aos poucos no seu código Java, ou seja, troca uma classe Java pela mesma classe escrita em Kotlin, e assim por diante.

Exemplos:

- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html
- https://medium.com/movile-tech/trocar-o-java-pelo-kotlin-8bed76014d99

Comment: Entendi, obrigada. Que na verdade eu comecei ao contrário, eu estudei o Kotlin quando lançou e agora que estou vendo a sintaxe do java. Mas respondeu minha pergunta já. Obrigada.

Comment: Sem problemas. Se a resposta lhe atendeu, você pode aceitá-la clicando no sinal de visto (✔) no canto superior esquerdo da resposta, abaixo da contagem dos votos.